# VS .NET Maui project seems to ignore .gitignore file

Tags: git, visual-studio, maui

Using the MonkeyFinder project as a base (Thank you James Montemagno!), I created a new project (different file and class names, etc.). However, when I commit files, either from VS or using GitExtensions, I get hundreds, if not thousands, of generated files that I don't want committed show up in the Unstaged files list. It's very time-consuming to go thru the Unstaged list to find the files that I DO want committed.

I'm using the exact same .gitignore as the MonkeyFinder project, and it's located in the top-level folder of my project.

Any ideas how to fix this? I'm wondering if it's a setting in git.

Comment: if you try git from the command line do you get the same results?

Comment: Is that "top-level folder" the highest folder in your **solution** (just to be clear, since you said "project")? Is it the same folder that contains hidden `.vs` folder? Are you sure its name isn't `.gitignore.txt`? Or contain a blank or any other character that alters its name? If you download from source repo to a new folder, does `.gitignore` file get downloaded too`?  If not, it wasn't correctly added; try selecting it and commiting it to the source repo. Worst case, you might need to use command line to commit it.

Comment: Thanks so much for your comment! The .gitignore file is in the same directory as .sln file and the .vs folder, which BTW is NOT hidden. The filename also has neither an extension nor any invisible characters, such as spaces. As far as your "download from source repo" suggestion goes, I'm not quite sure what you mean or how to do that.

Comment: Does `git status` on the command line show these files as untracked? Can you include a screenshot to help people understand what you're seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by creating a new solution from scratch rather than trying to modify an existing solution. Thanks to all respondents.